# Spring MVC - Mapping to .htm doesn't work

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I want to crate a simple hello world following a tutorial step by step, but I think that missing something, because my code returns just a 404

Please, can you help me with what is wrong?

This is the Controller class

```
package com.companyname.springapp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
/**
 * Created by cota on 22/12/15.
 */
@Controller
public class HelloController{

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

@RequestMapping(value="/hello.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String now = (new Date()).toString();
    logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

    return new ModelAndView("views/hello.jsp", "now", now);

}
}
```

This is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Springapp</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springapp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is the app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.web" />

</beans>
```

This is a header file to include all the JSP files

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
```

And the index.jsp and hello.jsp have the next line

```
<%@ include file="views/include.jsp" %>
```

It's my first question here and really admire all of you, sorry for my poor english!

Comment: ...what's your view resolver configuration? I think you have other issues, but it's better to go step by step.

Comment: What endpoint do you hit? What output do you see from your server when it starts up?

Comment: Most likely that the problem is because Spring can't find file `views/hello.jsp`. How did you configure `ViewResolver`?

Comment: you can post your url?

Answer (score -1):

I don`t think so you have not properly configured view resolver. so, please try the below links. It may be work for you.
Open your app-config.xml and add the below lines.

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

and modify the your controller as below.

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/hello.htm",method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest     request,HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

String now = (new Date()).toString();
logger.info("Returning hello view with " + now);

return new ModelAndView("hello", "now", now);
```

}

I hope this will work for you..

Comment: Why do you suggest these changes? What will they accomplish? Why was it wrong before?

Comment: ModelAndView("views/hello.jsp", "now", now) How he can return view with .jsp extension if he has already configured viewResover. He is getting because of configurations.  @Coat didn`t mention those things.

Comment: Right. I'd like you to edit your answer and clarify all that.